# How can I reuse environment specific variables?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Say we have 2 logical environments "Staging" and "Production".
How or where can I define a variable that will have the value X on staging and Y on production **AND** be able to reuse those variables when I create more than 1 release definition?

An example would be the URL of a Web API to be used by all applications released on that environment.

For example I have these environment specific variables:

```
Staging
ApiUrl: https://staging.api.com

Production
ApiUrl: https://production.api.com
```

And I want to create 2 release definitions to deploy products (that both use that Api) to both environments.

1. If I add the ApiUrl as environment variables I need to add and maintain those variables on ALL release definition environments. Not very maintainable?
2. If I create a variable group "StagingVariables" and "ProductionVariables" I don't think I can switch/choose which group to use on which environment? You can link multiple variable groups to a release definition, but not to a specific environment, right?
3. You can define release definition variables which would combine the worst of the above 2 options.

If there's no decent way to solve this, are there way to help reduce the maintainance burden? Bulk editing environment variables for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assessment seems to be correct. The only way I can think of is to programmatically overwrite the variable values from a PowerShell script at the start of an environment.

Or, I think you can create a variable in the environment and set the value to a variable in the variable group, eg:

```
Variable Group Staging
  - Staging.ApiUri
Variable Group Prod
  - Prod.ApiUri

Environment Staging
  - ApiUri = $(Staging.ApiUri)
Environment Prod
  - ApiUri = $(Prod.ApiUri)
```

That way the value is still defined in one location, but explicitly scoped at the release level.

Comment: Your second approach could work quite well. It's still a bit more work than I would have hoped for (adding all the uniformly named variables per environment) but at least there's a single location of the actual values. Thanks.